# JQuery UI inline DatePicker loses date after ASP.NET postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an inline DatePicker (Week-Picker) initiaized as follows, which on Select fires a ASP.NET click event. It functions fine and my ASP code does it's part, however if I select a date for ex: after advancing the month by the DatePicker's next/prev buttons, when the page refreshes after postback, the DatePicker returns to the current month...Also it loses the selected startDate / endDate Range in the selectCurrentWeek() method here.

```
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

$('.week-picker').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#txtDP1').val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, date, inst.settings));
            selectCurrentWeek();
            DP1_Submit();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

        $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function () { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function () { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

The hidden field/button are:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDP1" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDP1" runat="server" Text="Go" style="display:none;"  />
```

I have tried using the setDate() method, and defaultDate property without success. Help?

Answer (score 0):

**use hidden filed instead of textbox. the value losing because of  style="display:none;" in text box.**

```
<asp:HiddenField id="txtDP1" value="" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: if u want u can change attribute id as hdnDp1 and also change in jquery and .cs page.

Comment: remove  style="display:none;"  and check value is coming on postback